# Copying data between sheets to specific rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Stack Overflow, Google scripts, and a beginner in JavaScript, so please forgive any rookie errors.

Here's a run down of what my Google spreadsheet does and what I'm trying to accomplish.

*Sheet One* is full of data, each row containing an ID in column A.

In *Sheet Two*, the user inputs an ID into *Sheet Two's* column A and the sheet uses the value to perform a vlookup in *Sheet One* to pull the corresponding data into *Sheet Two*.

The user then uses this data to access certain things and enters extra data into *Sheet Two*, sometimes replacing the lookup's values.

*Sheet Three* then copies over the data from *Sheet Two* and performs tests to ascertain whether new values have been entered, structuring the data so that it's ready to replace the data originally taken from *Sheet One*. This includes generating a MATCH position on the ID to find the relative row position in *Sheet One*.

All of that works fine up until there but now I need to create a executable function that uses the MATCH position (referenced as loc below) to find the correct row in *Sheet One*  and replace the original data with the data from *Sheet Three*.

Here's what I've come up with but I'm not having much luck getting it working:

```
    function values() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
     sheet = ss.getSheets()[2],
     range = sheet.getDataRange(),
     values = range.getValues();

  for (var r=1; r<values.length; r++) {
   var row = values[r],
       a = row[0],
       b = row[1],
       val = row[2],
       res = row[3],
       run = row[4],
       crun = row[5],
       test = row[6],
       notes = row[7],
       auc1 = row[8],
       auc2 = row[9],
       auc3 = row[10],
       auc4 = row[11],
       sold = row[12],
       loc = row[13];


   function getRa(a,b,val,res,run,crun,test,notes,auc1,auc2,auc3,auc4,sold,loc){

 var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var range2 = sheet2.getRange(loc, 2, 1, 13);
range2.setValues(a,b,val,res,run,crun,test,notes,auc1,auc2,auc3,auc4,sold);

   }
 }
};
```

I also need it to stop looping once it gets to a blank row in *Sheet Three*, but I've yet to figure out a way to do this within the function.

Can someone let me know if I'm on the right track?

Or help me to understand how I should be achieving this if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow!

You tried but it's a bit off track, I've updated your code and commented it to get you back in the right direction, not tested but should work:

```
function values() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheets()[2],
      range = sheet.getDataRange(),
      values = range.getValues(),
      sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Get the sheet at start, if you do it inside the loop it will search the sheet everytime, which will consume more time

  var row, range2; // Initiate the variables before hand, even if not using them right now, makes the code cleaner and it's good practice

  for (var r=1; r<values.length; r++) {
    if( values[r].join('') === '' ) return 'Blank row encountered'; // Joins the entire row and checks if it has anything

    row = values[r]; // This will return just an Array, not double anymore

    // No need to create a new function

    // SetValues accepts an Array of Array (see documentation), which is exactly what getValues returns
    // Also setValues return the range, so you can store it for later
    range2 = sheet2.getRange(row[13], 2, 1, 13) // uses chaining (google it)
                   .setValues( [ row ] ); // Encapsule's the row in another array to make a Double Array, required
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take a look Kriggs, it makes a lot more sense to me this way. Unfortunately, google scripts is spitting out the following error: Cannot find method getRange((class),number,number,number). (line 209, file "") - any ideas?

Comment: Yes, `row[13]` isn't returning a number, log it before the `getRange`. You can do so by: `Logger.log( 'row[13] is ' + row[13] )`, then run the code and press CTRL + Enter to check the log.